# Alphabet Triangle

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make alphabet triangle like "Akshay"

```
a=raw_input("Enter the name of the School")
l=list()
for i in a:
    l.append(i)
print l
z=0
empty=" "
for i in l:
    print
    for j in range(0,z+1):
        kl=l(j)
        print empty+j,
    z+=1
```

I got result this 
    Enter the name of the SchoolAkshay
    ['A', 'k', 's', 'h', 'a', 'y']

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/triaangle.py", line 12, in <module>
    kl=l(j)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

i want result like this

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
    kl=l(j)
```

to

```
    kl=l[j]
```

Thats the index operator. () is the call operator.

Comment: You have more problems in your code, I answered why you are getting the "'list' object is not callable" error

Answer (score 0):

Use the following example for [reference](http://www.makeforsure.com/e-learning/c-program-print-alphabet-triangle/):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int ch=65;
    int i,j,k,m;
    clrscr();
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for(j=5;j>=i;j–)
            printf(” “);
        for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
            printf(“%c”,ch++);
            ch–;
        for(m=1;m<i;m++)
            printf(“%c”,–ch);
        printf(“\n”);
        ch=65;
    }
   getch();
}
```

Output:

```
     A
    ABA
   ABCBA
  ABCDCBA
 ABCDEDCBA
```